# How can I access a loop item's object through __vue__?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm rendering a list in Vue and trying to implement some collision detection. I'm looking to return the exact same object as 'item' through `[DomElement].__vue__`

Is there a property on `__vue__` that matches the object of the item? Where is this stored?

*data:*

```
items: [
    { name: 'one' }, 
    { name: 'two' }
]
```

*component:*

```
<icon 
  v-for="item in items" 
  @click="match(item, $el)">
      
  {{ item.name }}
</icon>
```

*method:*

```
match(item, el){
    console.log(item === el.__vue__) // how can I make these match?
    // el.__vue__.whereCanIFindItem ??
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

A bit more information on why I'm doing this:

I'm trying to convert the [selection.js](https://simonwep.github.io/selection/) library into a Vue component. Essentially when a DOM element is clicked, it returns an `event.target` - and from that I'm trying to get a reference back to the object that rendered it. When I run a comparison between the item object from the loop and the item's `[DOMelement].__vue__` I get a false result.

I know the `item` and the item's dom `__vue__` property are the same, but they're not returning true in comparison checks `===`.

Comment: Why do you need to get `item` in that way?

Comment: It's complicated, this is essentially psuedo code to try and find the answer

Comment: I can't conceive of a reason why you would need to do this, but `__vue__` is just a reference to the root Vue, so the `items` data array would just be `el.__vue__.items`.

Comment: The Item in the match method is the exact same object as the item in items.

Answer (score 1):

The Item in the match method is the exact same object as the item in items. Arrays do only store references on objects, item is no object than you have reason to get the same. v-for can give you also an index, use it to get property in the items array `items[idx]`

component:

```
<icon
  v-for="(item, index) in items" 
  @click="match(item, index, $el)">

  {{ item.name }}
</icon>
```

method:

```
match(item, index, el){
    console.log(this.items[index])
}
```

Comment: I probably explained myself wrong. I'm trying to convert the [selection.js](https://simonwep.github.io/selection/) library into a Vue component. Essentially when a DOM element is clicked, it returns an event.target - and from that I'm trying to get a reference back to the object that rendered it. When I run a comparison (===) against ```__vue__``` I get a false result.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by storing a reference on itself.

```
<icon 
  v-for="item in items"
  :itemObj="item"
  @click="match(item, $el)">

  {{ item.name }}
</icon>
```

then..

```
match(item, el){
    console.log(item === el.__vue__.itemObj) // true, woo!
}
```